# HTML Column size slider

Tags: html, css

I've recently been working on a small web based grid type object. What I want to do is add some sort of slider so that you can drag it and dynamically change the width of a column. At the moment this is just a vertical strip at the top-right hand side of each column.

My goal is to make this slider overflow the parent object and it's siblings. I've already searched for solutions and tried them. No amount of clever CSS positions and z-indexes worked.

Instead, half oc the slider gets cut from view and cannot be interacted with.

This is what the result is supposed to look like:
[app result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNCVJ.png)

As you can see the red strip is halfway over each column.

```css
    .wgrid_col{
        font-family: Arial;
     width: 100px;
     float:left;
     position: relative !important;
        background: rgb(220, 220, 220);
     overflow:visible !important;
     z-index:1;
    }
    
    .colSizeHandle{
     background:red;
     position:absolute !important;
     z-index:2;
     width:10px;
     height:42px;
     margin-left:95px;
     cursor:col-resize;
     top:0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wgrid" style="min-width: 380px;">
     <div id="ROWN" style="width: 70px;">
      <div id="hdr_rown">
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="col_A" class="wgrid_col">
      <div class="wgrid_col_hdr">A</div>
      <div class="colSizeHandle"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="col_B" class="wgrid_col">
      <div class="wgrid_col_hdr">B</div>
      <div class="colSizeHandle"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="col_C" class="wgrid_col">
      <div class="wgrid_col_hdr">C</div>
      <div class="colSizeHandle"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I know the effect of having the slider appear in front of the parent element and the parent's siblings is possible and I have done this before. But in this instance I can't get it to work for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit confused, can't tell what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, just remove the `z-index` from each `.wgrid_col`:

```css
.wgrid_col{
        font-family: Arial;
     width: 100px;
     float:left;
     position: relative !important;
        background: rgb(220, 220, 220);
     overflow:visible !important;
    }
    
    .colSizeHandle{
     background:red;
     position:absolute !important;
     z-index:2;
     width:10px;
     height:42px;
     margin-left:95px;
     cursor:col-resize;
     top:0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wgrid" style="min-width: 380px;">
     <div id="ROWN" style="width: 70px;">
      <div id="hdr_rown">
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="col_A" class="wgrid_col">
      <div class="wgrid_col_hdr">A</div>
      <div class="colSizeHandle"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="col_B" class="wgrid_col">
      <div class="wgrid_col_hdr">B</div>
      <div class="colSizeHandle"></div>
     </div>
     
     <div id="col_C" class="wgrid_col">
      <div class="wgrid_col_hdr">C</div>
      <div class="colSizeHandle"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

When you set a `z-index` on a parent element, it's children **can never** have a `z-index` greater than that. You set `z-index: 1` on the `.wgrid_col` which was the parent of the `colSizeHandle`. `colSizeHandle` had a `z-index: 2`, but that wasn't working because it's parent was to `z-index: 1`.